# Is it true that /abbb/ does not match /ab+c?/

Tags: regex

This is from an online quiz I am taking. Makes no sense to me though, because abbb:

1. Starts with mandatory a - check!
2. Has one or more b's after a - check!
3. Has 0 occurance of c - check!

Thoughts? Am I missing something here?

Comment: Did the quiz not have an explanation?

Comment: Nope, just a random online quiz I found. I guess I just wanted confirmation that I'm not wrong since I've only just started learning this stuff.

Comment: To be pedantic, depending on the language `/ab+c?/` does not necessarily mean "starts with".

Comment: @whoshotya What is the whole question of the quiz? Do you have a screenshot/link?

Comment: @kennytm Link to questions: https://regex.sketchengine.co.uk/extra_regexps.html it's #2. link to answers: https://regex.sketchengine.co.uk/answers.html apperantly for question 2 only #1 is right

Comment: @whoshotya Well looks like the site is wrong then.

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple online regex tools you can use to test that out.

https://regex101.com/ is an ad-free site with multiple regex implementations (php, javascript, python, and golang). Here's a link with your test case: https://regex101.com/r/9uI9Uw/1.

Your reasoning is correct and `abbb` is a match for the regex `/ab+c?/`.

Javascript snippet:

```js
const s = 'abbb'
console.log(s.match(/ab+c?/))
```

Answer (score 0):

According to your description,I think that you want is this.

```
^ab+[^c]*$
```